# How to create form fields like checkbox and input text with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, checkbox, pdfbox

I must programmaticaly create a pdf that contains a checkbox.
but I don't know how to do this. 
This is my code:

```
PDAcroForm form = new PDAcroForm(document);
PDCheckbox checkbox = new PDCheckbox(form, form.getDictionnary());
List<PDField> fields = form.getFields();
fields.add(checkbox);
form.setFields(fields);
```

My document is generated but the checkbox is not present. Any solution?

Comment: Form field creation seems to be a very manual task in PDFBox, at least I have not seen any easy examples. Dispersed forum or mailing list entries like [this one](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@pdfbox.apache.org/msg01369.html) might get you going. You'll need to understand the sections on forms, widgets, and annotations from [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), though.

Comment: think, i will read this.

Comment: Did you solve this task? I Am facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, i but not the way i'm thinking first. I juste draw checkbox with line. I create function that create checkbox. Something like this : drawCheckbox(int top, int left, int size, boolean checked);. good luck. Maybe the new api work better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343232/how-to-add-a-border-to-a-checkbox-and-make-it-always-visible