# Java PDFBox 2.0 how to check PDCheckBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to input a checkBox field in a pdf form. And with this I do not have an issue, but when I'm trying to set the value to "check" I got a error message:

**value 'Yes' is not a valid option for the field wypoczynkowyCheckBox, valid values are: [] and Off**

```
 public static void addChackBox(PDAcroForm acroForm, PDPage page, 
    int x, int y, int wight, int hight, String fieldName) throws IOException {

    PDCheckBox field = new PDCheckBox(acroForm);
    field.setPartialName(fieldName);
    acroForm.getFields().add(field);  

    field.setValue("Yes");

    PDAnnotationWidget widget = field.getWidgets().get(0);
    PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x, y, wight, hight);
    widget.setRectangle(rect);
    widget.setPage(page);
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
}
```

In each example that I found it is correct way. I do not have any ideal for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343232/how-to-add-a-border-to-a-checkbox-and-make-it-always-visible ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be:

```
field.check();
```

Comment: I use version: 2.0.7, also try to use chec() bu in this case I recive: java.lang.NullPointerException org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDButton.updateByValue(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDButton.updateByValue)

Comment: Also tested: ((PDCheckBox) field).check();
field.setValue(((PDCheckbox) field).getOnValue()); I do not have idea whta to solve this issue.

Comment: What I missed in my (deleted) comment, and maybe you missed too, is that the OP tries to create a checkbox, not just check it.